# How do I stop image overflow while using scale() property?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, overflow

While hovering the image, everything seems to be okay expect it is growing from top.
Even though, I have used a container `outer div` and set property `overflow: hidden;`.
Another issue is , I have used `border-radius: 4px`  on inner div, but I can see it working on the `top-left` and `top-right` corners only. Why it is not being shown in `bottom corners`.

**What I feel for this?**
I can see the `border-radius` working when I set `width: auto` and `height: auto` but now `overflow` won't work because of this. What's the better idea?

```css
.outer-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}


.box:hover:before
 {
   content:'Hello coder';
   font-family: cursive;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px cyan;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding-left: 10px;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 2;
}
.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  padding: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
<div class="box">
  <img src=" https://r1.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4427/Green-Nature-iPad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_200.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just cleaned up a little. The border-radius wasn't working because it was on the child within the parent (which was overflow: hidden) so when the scale happened the border-radius was hidden by the parent container.

Flex display will allow to use margin: auto which will take up the available space (positive or negative) so when the scale moves greater than 1 it turns into an auto negative value, keeping it centered. Alternatively you could do absolute positioning but this is cleaner;)

```css
.outer-box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
    }
    .box {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }


    .box:hover:before
     {
       content:'Hello coder';
       font-family: cursive;
       font-weight: bold;
       text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px cyan;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding-left: 10px;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       position:absolute;
       background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
       z-index: 2;
    }
    .outer-box:hover .box {
      transform: scale(1.2);
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="outer-box">
    <div class="box">
      <img src=" https://r1.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4427/Green-Nature-iPad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_200.jpg">
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: yeah,  thanks. That `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` was helpful from your code. Don't know how I forget that simple. That`:: before`  pseudo element is not working fine with your code. I have answered my own question. Check that one. `margin-top` on `.box` was causing trouble for that `::before` element.

Answer (score 0):

After few tweaks, I found what I was doing wrong.
I have made the following changes from in original code.

```
.box {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       /*margin-top: 10px I removed this one. Couldn't figure why I used in first hand, it was causing trouble for scale() property*/
```

}

> I have also removed z-index from `.box:hover::before` , it is of no use.